# Plot phase portrait of three-variable system of kinetic equations

Tags: derivatives, systems-of-equations, vector-fields, wolfram-alpha

I have a system of three kinetic equations with three variables $x,y,z$, i.e. :
$$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=f(x,y,z)$$
$$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=g(x,y,z)$$
$$\dfrac{dz}{dt}=p(x,y,z)$$

In WolframAlpha you can just put functions into `vector field()` function and get the phase portrait. How can do it for eqations with 3 variables as simple as in WolframAplha `vector field`?